# quartz clustered scheduler deadlock

Tags: mysql, quartz-scheduler

We randomly get below exception while running quartz clustered scheduler on 6 instances:

> Couldn't acquire next trigger: Deadlock found when trying to get lock;
>   try restarting transaction

Here is our quartzConfig.properties

```
    scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true
    scheduler.instanceName = 'quartzScheduler'
    scheduler.instanceId = 'AUTO'
    threadPool.threadCount = 13
    threadPool.threadPriority = 5
    jobStore.misfireThreshold = 300000
    jobStore.'class' = 'org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX'
    jobStore.driverDelegateClass = 'org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate'
    jobStore.useProperties = true
    jobStore.dataSource = 'myDS'
    jobStore.tablePrefix = 'QRTZ_'
    jobStore.isClustered = true
    jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 10000
    dataSource.myDS.driver='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
    dataSource.myDS.maxConnections = 15
```

We are using quartz grails plugins(with quartz 2.2.1) in our application with mysql db.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Couldn't find any other solution so we moved quartz tables to separate database. So far so good.

Comment: Did you try setting the maxConnections to 80 (6 servers * 13 threads + 2 suggested extra by Terracotta)? Not sure if the maxConnections is server specific or shared by the cluster.